# jQuery animations in forms

Tags: jquery, hide, show

let me start with my form:

http://jsfiddle.net/UCJpF/

I want to display only one line from the three below selectable options, based on selected stuff. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a good variety of ways to do that. Are there any limitations on the HTML?

Comment: Nope it's just like shown. And I guess val() is the answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your fiddle that should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/JZNMy/

The key points are that I reference the row showing the message to the selected option using the value on the option plus '-message' as the id of the message row. Then, I bound to the `.change` event of the select box, which gets the currently selected value, hides all of the messages, then shows the related one.

**EDIT**: I updated the fiddle link with one that automatically triggers the `change` event on the select box to make sure one of the messages is displayed.

Comment: Sorry, but that's buggy, when you open the site for the first time there's nothing below Option 1 (let me add that the first selected option may vary).

Comment: @anon: Directly below the event handler you can manually trigger the `change` event to force it to update to the currently selected option: `$('#select-box').trigger('change');`: http://jsfiddle.net/JZNMy/